# How to fix problem when find all text matches regular expression in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to get all text match with date regex on given string but i don't get expected result

i have string like this "Lomba lari akan diadakan pada tanggal 15 Agustus 2019"

```perl
@dates2 = $line =~ m/(\d{1,2}\s(Januari|Februari|Maret|April|Mei|Juni|Juli|Agustus|September|Oktober|November|Desember)\s\d{4})/g;
    $length2 = @dates2;
    print "@dates2\n";
    print "Length 2 : $length2\n";
    $date_occurence += $length2;
```

i want to get only "15 Agustus 2019" in array dates2 but i got "15 Agustus 2019" and "Agustus". Anyone can tell me how match regex code work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting `Agustus` in the output because of the month alternation `(Januari|...|Desember)` which is a capturing group. To remove it, just make your internal alternation non-capturing i.e.

```
(?:Januari|Februari|Maret|April|Mei|Juni|Juli|Agustus|September|Oktober|November|Desember)
```